# InquirerJS | "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error when

Tags: javascript, node.js, inquirer, inquirerjs

I'm trying to run the InquirerJS example problem, as documented here: https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/blob/master/packages/inquirer/examples/pizza.js

Unfortunately, when trying to do so, I get this TypeError. I'm running the file through my command line, "node pizza.js". It works just fine if I remove the .then() call, but then I can't do much with the output.

I'm running node v10.16.0 and npm 6.9.0
I'm running the code using the command 'node pizza.js' in my command line

```js
const inquirer = require('inquirer');

const questions = [
    {
        type: 'confirm',
        name: 'toBeDelivered',
        message: 'Is this for delivery?',
        default: false
    }
];

inquirer.prompt(questions).then(answers => {
    console.log(answers);
});
```

Comment: I just tried this with your exact code and it works as expected. Node v10.1, npm 5.6.

Comment: Feels pretty silly, but I think I was able to fix it by just uninstalling and reinstalling Inquirer. Not sure why it wasn't working before, but at least this fixed it!